# hibernate : sorting null values

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I have 3 entity classes: `Pair`, `BATBpa` and `SNSBPa`. 
Entity class Pair has dependencies such as `pair.snsBpa` and `pair.batBpa`.

I have a table of `Pair` entities and when I sort them, for example:

```
ORDER BY pair.snsBpa.snsId (snsId is string)
```

hql deletes rows where `pair.snsBpa` is `null`. How to make hql not to delete null rows ? here is my hql request:

```
SELECT p FROM Pair p LEFT JOIN FETCH p.batBpa LEFT JOIN FETCH p.snsBpa ORDER BY p.snsBpa.snsId asc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. The point is that this piece of code in hibernate

```
ORDER BY p.snsBpa.snsId
```

create a cross join expression in the mssql request, that's why there are no rows typeof PAIR where `p.snsBpa == null`. That's why i created an alias :

```
SELECT p FROM Pair p LEFT JOIN FETCH p.batBpa bat LEFT JOIN FETCH p.snsBpa sns ORDER BY sns.snsId asc
```

This alias creation deletes cross joins from pure sql request and i got all rows with null and not-null values.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
SELECT p FROM Pair p LEFT JOIN FETCH p.batBpa LEFT JOIN FETCH p.snsBpa ORDER BY p.snsBpa.snsId asc NULLS LAST
```

**edit**:

```
SELECT p FROM Pair p LEFT JOIN FETCH p.batBpa LEFT JOIN FETCH p.snsBpa ORDER BY
CASE WHEN p.snsBpa.snsId IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
  p.snsBpa.snsId ASC
```